# After installation of bumblebee: i386 OpenGL Apps stopped working

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, intel, bumblebee, mesa

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my notebook (ASUS K53SV, i7-2670QM, Intel HD 3000, GeForce 540M).
In order to save energy i've installed "bumblebee", a solution for Nvidia Optimus Technology on Linux.

So far, so good.

Since then, the lifetime of my battery increased a lot.

But: If i try to open 32-Bit Apps like Wine and this Application uses OpenGL, it doesn't work. It just runs on my 540M, when I put "optirun" before the "wine" command.
But, for simple OpenGL Applications i don't need the power of my dedicated GPU.

I've used the offical bumblebee instalation guide, therefore i've installed, the Packages like "virtualgl-libs:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386" of course.

So, what can i do to get my OpenGL accerleration on 32-Bit Applications working again?

Thank you very much for your help!
- PhenomZ

BTW: My system sould by up to date. I'm always installing the recent updates.
(I'm also using the Xorg-Edgers PPA)

```
    phenom@notebook:~/Downloads/Test$ wine test.exe
err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"OPENGL32.dll": libGL.so.1: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
err:module:import_dll Loading library OPENGL32.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\phenom\\Downloads\\Test\\test.exe") failed (error c000007a).
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\home\\phenom\\Downloads\\Test\\test.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Comment: Please attach the output of `update-alternatives --display i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf` to your question

Comment: Okay, here it is:

`i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf - manueller Modus

  Link verweist zur Zeit auf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/alt_ld.so.conf

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf - Priorität 500
  Slave i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/alt_ld.so.conf - Priorität 9700
Gegenwärtig »beste« Version ist »/usr/lib/nvidia-current/alt_ld.so.conf«.`

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed libgl1-mesa-glx:i386? After doing so, try reinstalling Bumblebee.

Comment: Whoa, thank you very much!
After I reinstalled bumblebee... now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I'll explain what happened. In Bumblebee version before 3.0-2~...ppa1, installing the `bumblebee` package also installs `bumblebee-nvidia` which on its turn installs `nvidia-current`.

The `nvidia-current` package installs both the 64-bit and 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system. These OpenGL libraries conflict with the Mesa OpenGL library, package `libgl1-mesa-glx`. (read: breaks OpenGL capabilities on systems where the primary X server does not use the nvidia driver like an Optimus laptop)

The `bumblebee-nvidia` package tries to repair this by setting the default OpenGL library to the Mesa one for installed architectures. Initially, only `libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64` is installed. So, unless `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` is installed before, OpenGL gets broken for 32-bit architectures.

<del>The solution is to first install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, and then install Bumblebee. `virtualgl-libs:i386` can be installed at any time and will also be installed like bumblebee-nvidia in later versions.</del> New installations will automatically pull in the drivers in the right order.

If you've already installed Bumblebee, simply install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` and reinstall `bumblebee-nvidia`.